# Loaded does not exist on inherited BaseDiagramPage

Tags: c#, inheritance, uwp

I have a `BaseDiagramPage` class which inherits directly from `Page`. The idea is that it will hold common functionality across multiple pages (let me know if this is a bad way to do it). But my `XAML` classes implementing `BaseDiagramPage` are complaining that `this.Loaded` does not exist. It works fine if I inherit from `Page` directly in the `XAML` class.

The `BaseDiagramPage` class can literally have nothing in it.

Any insights would be appreciated.

```
public sealed partial class EmptyPage : BaseDiagramPage
{
    public EmptyPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        // this property does not exist, BaseDiagramPage is public
        this.Loaded += (sender, e) =>
        {
            // load something
        };
    }
}
```

EDIT:

BaseDiagramPage source

```
namespace CoreProject.Pages
{
    public class BaseDiagramPage : Page
    {

    }
}
```

EDIT EDIT:

Using `base.Loaded` works, but is that right? I want to call my classes `Loaded`

```
base.Loaded += (sender, e) =>
{
};
```

Comment: Please include the source code for `BaseDiagramPage`

Comment: Edited my question

Comment: Thanks, that was helpful :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you forgot to change the **XAML** part of your `EmptyPage`, so just change

```
<Page x:Class="xxx.EmptyPage" ...>
    ...
</Page>
```

to

```
<local:BaseDiagramPage x:Class="xxx.EmptyPage" ...>
    ...
</local:BaseDiagramPage>
```

After doing this, you can even remove the inheritance from your *C#* code as it's now redundant. So the following would just work.

```
public sealed partial class EmptyPage
```

Comment: Also, it errors on `this` because your current page object is invalid; but the base page is still valid and that's why once you change to it the error is gone.